# Append selected file to Input

Tags: jquery, file-upload, image-uploading

i have a input with multiple file selected, them preview them in browser:

```
<input type="file" name="imageUploader[]"  id="imageUploader" multiple/>
```

Preview use jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        function readURL(input)
        {
            if (input.files)
            {
                var html = '';

                for(i = 0; i < input.files.length ; i++)
                {
                    var reader = new FileReader();  

                    reader.onload = function (e)
                     {
                        html = '<img src="'+ e.target.result +'"/>';
                        $('.reviewUpload').after(html);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                }
            }
        }

     $("#imageUploader").change(function(e)
      {

        alert(this.files.length);
         //submit the form here
            readURL(this);
        });
    })
</script>
```

and process upload from the browser by PHP:

```
$img = $_FILES["imageUploader"];

 //count how many file selected
 $count = count($_FILES['productImage']['name']);

//Move image in order to folder
for($i = 0; $i< $count; $i++)
{
      $tmp = $img["tmp_name"];
      move_uploaded_file($img["tmp_name"][$i],"/img/product/".$i.".jpg");
}
```

Assume i selected first 3 images, browser will preview that 3 images.

In the second click to select file, i pick 2 image.

After submit them to server, the server just receive only last 2 images which I selected.

How can i add last there images to $_FILES[] array in browser ?
If work correctly as i want, server receive 5 images.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you select files second time the files previously added are vanished so that they will not be available to your server.

You can do this by implementing your code using `Add more files` functionality.